# Filter records by value - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I need that depending on the user who is logged in, different records/files are displayed. Each user will be assigned different records/files to manage. Although they can be filtered with the search bar, the idea would be that everyone can see the ones assigned to them, for a matter of security and neatness. From where would it be more convenient to do this?

[This is the Index view of my system, where only the records/files assigned to the user should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy4bO.png)

I leave you a portion of this index view of the controller

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Siniestro;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    //mail
    use App\Mail\ContactanosMailable;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
    
    
    
    
    
    class SiniestroController extends Controller
    {
    
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('permission:ver-siniestro|crear-siniestro|editar-siniestro|borrar-siniestro')->only('index');
            $this->middleware('permission:crear-siniestro', ['only'=>['create','store']]);
            $this->middleware('permission:editar-siniestro|derivar-siniestro', ['only'=>['edit','update']]);
            $this->middleware('permission:borrar-siniestro', ['only'=>['destroy']]);
        }
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $siniestros = Siniestro::paginate(50);
    
              //return DB::select('select localidad from siniestros'); //---> Devuelve los datos de la columna estados
        
            
            return view('siniestros.index', compact('siniestros'));
    
            $now = Carbon::now();
        }
    
        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
```

view blade.index

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
     
        <section class="section">
            <div class="section-header">
                <h3 class="page__heading">Siniestros</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="section-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                    
                
                            @can('crear-siniestro')
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('siniestros.create') }}">Nuevo</a>
                            @endcan
                
                            <table class="table table-sm m-1 p-1 table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablita" style="width:100%">
                                    <thead style="background-color:hsl(213, 99%, 49%)">                                     
                                        <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Siniestro</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Coordinador</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Actualizado</th>                                    
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Patente</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Cliente</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Fecha ingreso</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Fecha gestión</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Captura de pantalla</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Estado</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Modalidad</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Observaciones</th>
                                        @can('derivar-siniestro')
                                        <!-- <th style="color:#fff;">Screenshot</th> -->
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Dirección</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Localidad</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Inspector</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Motivo</th>
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Enviar Orden</th>
                                        @endcan
                                        <th style="color:#fff;">Acciones</th>                                                                   
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                @foreach ($siniestros as $siniestro)
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="display: none;">{{ $siniestro->id }}</td>                                
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->siniestro }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->creator->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->editor->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->patente }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->cliente }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->created_at }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->updated_at }}</td>
                                    <td><img alt="img" src="/img/{{ $siniestro->imagen }}" width="100px"></td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->estado }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->modalidad }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->observaciones }}</td>
                                    @can('derivar-siniestro')
                                    <!-- <td><a href="{{ $siniestro->url }}" target="blank_" >Ver documento</a></td> -->
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->direccion }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->localidad }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->inspector }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->motivo }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $siniestro->enviarorden }}</td>
                                    @endcan
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="{{ route('siniestros.destroy',$siniestro->id) }}" method="POST">                                        
                                            @can('editar-siniestro')
                                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" href="{{ route('siniestros.edit',$siniestro->id) }}">Editar</a>
                                            @endcan
                                            
                                            
                                          
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            @can('borrar-siniestro')
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Borrar</button>
                                            @endcan
    
                                        </form>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
    
                            <!-- Paginacion a la derecha -->
                            <div class="pagination justify-content-end">
                                {!! $siniestros->links() !!}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Model

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Wildside\Userstamps\Userstamps;
    
    
    
    class Siniestro extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        use Userstamps;
       
        protected $fillable = ['created_by', 'imagen', 'updated_by', 'deleted_by', 'siniestro', 'patente', 'cliente', 'fechaip', 'estado', 'modalidad',
        'observaciones', 'fechacierre', 'compania', 'contacto', 'codigoinspeccion', 'inspector', 'direccion', 'localidad', 'telefono', 'motivo', 'link', 'enviarorden', 'email'];
    
    
       public function archivos()
       {
           return $this->hasMany(Archivo::class);
       }
    
    
    
    }
```

It occurs to me that the best thing would be to add a column to my database called, for example, "assigned to", and depending on the value, which would be the name of each user (Marcoz Perez, Germán López, etc., be the records/files that are listed.

I think I might be able to solve it with a "where" statement in the controller; but first, I don't know how to use it properly... and second, I don't know if from there I can get the result I'm looking for, paying attention to the different users.

Comment: Better use the id of the user than it's name, and then use `Siniestro::where(['user_id' => auth()->user->id])->paginate(50)`. You will need to add that user_id column and fill it when inserting the rows on the table

Answer (score 0):

If you let each user have a collection of siniestros in a hasMany relationship, you can gather just the ones connected to the user. So user might have this

```
// In user model
public function siniestros()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Siniestro::class);
}
```

Then in the index() you might do something like this:

```
{
    // Get the logged in user
    $currentUser = Auth::user();

    // Get the user's siniestros (whatever that means ;-) )
    $siniestros = $currentUser->siniestros;
    
    return view('siniestros.index', compact('siniestros'));
}
```

In the database you could either add a user_id column to the sinietros table (that is nullable, so no id means unassigned). And then the hasMany function would find these. Or you could do a manyToMany with a pivot table. If the siniestros can only be assigned to 0 or 1 user, I would go for a nullable user_id column.

You could maybe call this column "assigned_user_id" but then you'll need to specify this column name when you define the relationship in the model.